# how to get selected index in tableview inside collectionview ios swift

Tags: uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

UITableView-> table view cell -> collection view -> collection view cell.

when i click collection view cell only getting selected index of collection view cell.how to get index in table view.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to segue for another view you can use prepare to segue in your `UIViewController` and get the tableView index as well

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "segueHomeToDetail" {
            if let collectionCell: InfoCellView = sender as? InfoCellView {
                if let collectionView: UICollectionView = collectionCell.superview as? UICollectionView {
                    if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailViewController {
                        // Pass some data to YourViewController
                        // collectionView.tag will give your selected tableView index
                        destination.object = collectionCell.object

                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

I use this on my code and works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Implement The ScrollView Method For Getting Index Value Outside Tableview And Collection View.

```
 if scrollView == tableview {
            let contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y

            print("contentOffset: ", contentOffset)
            if (contentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
                print("scrolling Down")

            } else {
                print("scrolling Up")

            }
        }
        else{

            let pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width

            let page = Int(floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1)

            let index = IndexPath(row:(scrollView.tag),section:0) //scrollview.tag get the index value of tableview when collection view scroll

        }
```